# How to decrease the memory consumption of Android Studio AVD emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, windows-8.1, android-virtual-device, android-studio-2.0

I am using android studio 2.0 in windows 8.1 , the memory consumption size is always about **2G** even if I have specified **64M VM heap,200M RAM and 200 Internal Storage** in ADB configuration

How can I decrease the memory consumption ?

note: The version of my emulator is **Nexus_5x API32**.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better if you actually don't use android studio AVD emulator. It's a very slow and memorykiller program!

Instead, use mobogeni or bluestacks.
They are quite faster than android studio avd and use lesser memory and of course have more abilities.

For downloading them, easily google them and download them free.

Working with them is very similar to android studio avd.

Run it, build and run your application and it shows itself in the devices list for running your app.

Comment: THX for your advice. I have installed genymotion and that is also very fast. But maybe because I imported some unknown jar packages, my project only can debug on the AVD emulator now.

Comment: yes, i have this problem with bluestacks too...
anyway in my opinion, the best thing for running and debugging your project is a physical android cell phone. these AVDs are just some alternatives.
my only solution for debugging problems with AVDs is using my cell phone!